# C# Windows Form using OracleDataAdapter to insert rows to a Oracle Table from a System DataTable

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio

I'm writing a windows form that populates a DataTable and I want it to insert into an Oracle Table.  I've seen some examples here that use the OracleDataAdapter to do this so I don't have to loop through all the records.  The code doesn't have any errors but when I check the Table using Toad(I did refresh) I don't see it.  I used the example below
[Update and insert records into Oracle table using OracleDataAdapter from DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020489/update-and-insert-records-into-oracle-table-using-oracledataadapter-from-datatab)
Here is how my DataTable is made:

```
    public DataTable dtMain = new DataTable();

    public void FillTable(DataTable dt)
    {
        dtMain.Columns.Add("SERIAL", typeof(System.String));
        dtMain.Columns.Add("LOCATION", typeof(System.String));
        dtMain.Columns.Add("UPC", typeof(System.String));
        dtMain.Columns.Add("PRODUCT", typeof(System.String));
        dtMain.Columns.Add("CREATED_BY", typeof(System.String));
        dtMain.Columns.Add("CREATED_DATE", typeof(System.DateTime));
        dtMain.Columns.Add("SKU", typeof(System.String));
        dtMain.Columns.Add("MAN_DATE", typeof(System.DateTime));
        dtUpload.Columns[0].Unique = true;
        dtMain.Merge(dt);

    }
```

This is the how I'm trying to insert into the database

```
    private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string strSelect = "SELECT serial, upc, man_date, location, product, created_by, created_date, serial from schema.table where rownum < 2";
string strInsert = "INSERT INTO schema.table (serial, upc, man_date, location, product, created_by, created_date, serial) VALUES (:serial, :upc, :man_date, :location, :product, :created_by, :created_date, :serial)";
string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(conStr);
connection.Open();
if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    return;
}
try
{
    OracleDataAdapter adapterS = new OracleDataAdapter();
    adapterS.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand(strSelect, connection);
    adapterS.Fill(dt);
    dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[0]);
    dt.Merge(dtUpload);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string x = ex.Message + ex.StackTrace;
    throw;
}
for (int i = 0; dt.Rows.Count > i; i++)
{

    OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
    adapter.InsertCommand = new OracleCommand(strInsert, connection);
    adapter.InsertCommand.BindByName = true;

    OracleParameter pSerial = new OracleParameter(":serial", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
    pSerial.SourceColumn = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName;
    pSerial.Value = dtUpload.Rows[i][0];

    OracleParameter pLocation = new OracleParameter(":location", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
    pLocation.SourceColumn = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName;
    pLocation.Value = dtUpload.Rows[i][1];

    OracleParameter pUPC = new OracleParameter(":upc", OracleDbType.Date);
    pUPC.SourceColumn = dt.Columns[2].ColumnName;
    pUPC.Value = dtUpload.Rows[i][2];

    OracleParameter pProduct = new OracleParameter(":product", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
    pProduct.SourceColumn = dt.Columns[3].ColumnName;
    pProduct.Value = dtUpload.Rows[i][3];

    OracleParameter pCreatedBy = new OracleParameter(":created_by", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
    pCreatedBy.SourceColumn = dt.Columns[4].ColumnName;
    pCreatedBy.Value = dtUpload.Rows[i][4];

    OracleParameter pCreatedDate = new OracleParameter(":created_date", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
    pCreatedDate.SourceColumn = dt.Columns[5].ColumnName;
    pCreatedDate.Value = dtUpload.Rows[i][5];

    OracleParameter pSKU = new OracleParameter(":SKU", OracleDbType.Date);
    pSKU.SourceColumn = dt.Columns[6].ColumnName;
    pSKU.Value = dtUpload.Rows[i][6];

    OracleParameter pManDate = new OracleParameter(":man_date", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
    pManDate.SourceColumn = dt.Columns[7].ColumnName;
    pManDate.Value = dtUpload.Rows[i][7];

    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(pSerial);
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(pLocation);
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(pUPC);
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(pProduct);
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(pCreatedBy);
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(pCreatedDate);
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(pserial);
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(pManDate);
}
try
{
    adapter.Update(dt);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string x = ex.Message + ex.StackTrace;
    throw;
}
connection.Close();
connection.Dispose();
```

}

If someone can give me some pointers that would be great, I've been Googling for 2 days and I just can't figure it out.  I bet it's something simple

**Update:**

Thank you for the reply, it took me a bit to get back to this project.  When I posted this I didn't realize I forgot to include my select statement.

For the OracleParameter value, I thought using SourceColumn would use that column for the values.

I did update the DataTable with the serial being unique.  It still doesn't insert the data.  If I included the Parameter.value would I have loop row by row to do this?  Above I corrected/updated it with the current code.

**Second Update:**

Ok, I tried looping through the parameters to add the values from the DataTable, no errors but still not inserting in the database.  I know my connectionstring is correct because the select query works.  The code above has been updated for the changes I made.  If some Oracle guru can shed some light on my problem a virtual high-five is waiting for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem, the row state in the DataTable needs to in the state of Added for it to work.  If someone else has this problem here is my new code and you can compare it to what I was trying to do.  Thank you Wernfried Domscheit for the Oracle part but it turned out to be my DataTable was the issue though setting the Unique column was probably an issue as well, I didn't check.  The OracleCommandBuilder took care of the insert statements and parameters for me.

```
    private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string strSelect = "SELECT serial, upc, man_date, location, product, created_by, created_date, serial from schema.table where rownum < 2";
    string strInsert = "INSERT INTO schema.table (serial, upc, man_date, location, product, created_by, created_date, serial) VALUES (:serial, :upc, :man_date, :location, :product, :created_by, :created_date, :serial)";
    string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
    OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(conStr);
    connection.Open();
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        return;
    }
    OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(strSelect, conStr);
    OracleCommandBuilder builder = new OracleCommandBuilder(adapter);
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    dt.Columns["SERIAL"].Unique = true;
    dt.Merge(dtUpload);
    dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[0]);
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        row.SetAdded();
    }

    try
    {
        adapter.Update(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string x = ex.Message + ex.StackTrace;
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used `OracleDataAdapter` but I see these possible issues:

- I don't think you can use `OracleDataAdapter` straight away, first you have to select an existing table from Oracle and based on this result you can do Update/Insert/Delete on it. Where is your `strSelect` string? I don't see it.
- You created all the `OracleParameter` but I don't see that you assign any value to it, they are all empty. I would expect something like `pOptoroLP.Value = ...;` before you make any insert.
- You should define a unique, resp. Primary Key column like `dt.Columns["SERIAL"].Unique = true;` in order to make `Update()` or `Delete()`. Maybe it is not required for `Insert()`, I don't know.

Did you follow the examples in [Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleDataAdapterClass.htm)